# Вычисления с массивами c#

Tags: c#, массивы

У меня есть входной массив, причем я инициализирую его.
Затем мне необходимо выполнить операции сложения,вычитания,сложения или деления с определенным элементом массива.
Конечно же ничего не работает,если просто обратиться к определенному элементу массива и умножить его например на 30.
вот вырванный кусок кода, как можно его переделать,чтобы все заработало?

Comment: конкретно напиши, что ты хочешь сделать с массивом, а не выкладывай листинги матана(

Comment: @Otis666 у меня есть матрица типа double. Мне необходимо сделать вычисления с опр. элементами массива,как я и описала ранее

Comment: опр. элементами, не очень понятно( скажи лучше на каком уровне вложенности они находятся и на какой позиции, а то мне не по себе от такого количества матана)

Comment: @Otis666  допустим это.         double[ ] array2 = new double[ ] { 250.0, 10.0, 1.0, 70.0, 70.0, 1.0 }; 
            if (Console.WriteLine(array2[4]) <= (30.0 *Console.WriteLine(array2[1]) + 30 * h_r))

Comment: А как вот этот, извините за выражение, бред должен работать? `if (Console.WriteLine(array2[4]) <= (30.0 *Console.WriteLine(array2[1]) + 30 * h_r))` ?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` делает "вывод на экран", вы это влепили где надо и где не надо. Где нужно вывести - там оставьте, а где вычисления - уберите, напр.: `q = 1 - 30 * (h_r + Console.WriteLine(array2[1])) / Console.WriteLine(array2[4]);` замениите на `q = 1 - 30 * (h_r + array2[1]) / array2[4];` и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо,сейчас исправлю. В программировании совсем чайник,поэтому и учусь поэтапно на своих же ошибках.

Comment: мои глазки, мои бедные глазки( для начала убери Console.WriteLine из условия if

Comment: Пожалуйста, но есть такие понятие как компиляция и отладка. Компилировать свой код пробовали? На этом этапе он бы уже выдал Вам ошибки/предупреждения с указанием конкретных мест. Потом идет уже отладка скомпилированного кода...

Comment: @MaxZS я знала,что тут полный бред,но как исправить не знала,поэтому и обратилась за помощью

Comment: Ну Вы же когда пишите код, наверное, исходите из каких-то предположений, как он будет работать и что он должен делать. И если в каком-то конкретном месте компилятор указывает, что нельзя умножить целое на пустое, то, смотрим в это место и ищем где-же это пустое? И почему оно пустое, когда я ожидала здесь увидеть число? А может потому что здесь функция возвращает пустое? А вообще, зачем я сюда эту функцию вставила? Ну и как-то так далее :)

Answer (score 3):

И в итоге, после всех манипуляций должно получиться что то вроде этого.
 P.S. скобочки не проверял.

```
        .....
        double[] array2 = new double[] { 250.0, 10.0, 1.0, 70.0, 70.0, 1.0 };

        if (array2[4] <= (30.0 * array2[1] + 30 * h_r)){
            q = A_m = 0;
            Console.WriteLine($"q= {q.ToString()}\r\nA_m= {A_m.ToString()} дБ");
        }
        else
        {
            q = 1 - 30 * (h_r + array2[1]) / array2[4];
            Console.WriteLine($"q= {q.ToString()} ");
        }

        double dAr4elem = (1 - Math.Exp(-array2[4] / 50));

        a_h_r = 1.5 + 3.0 * Math.Exp(-0.12 * Math.Sqrt(h_r - 5)) * (dAr4elem + 5.7 * Math.Exp(-0.09 * Math.Sqrt(h_r)) * (1 - Math.Exp(-2.8 * Math.Pow(10, -6) - Math.Sqrt(array2[4]))));
        a_h_s = 1.5 + 3.0 * Math.Exp(-0.12 * Math.Sqrt(array2[1] - 5)) * (dAr4elem + 5.7 * Math.Exp(-0.09 * Math.Sqrt(array2[1])) * (1 - Math.Exp(-2.8 * Math.Pow(10, -6) - Math.Sqrt(array2[4]))));
        b_h_s = 1.5 + 8.6 * Math.Exp(-0.09 * Math.Sqrt(array2[1])) * dAr4elem;
        b_h_r = 1.5 + 8.6 * Math.Exp(-0.09 * Math.Sqrt(h_r)) * dAr4elem;
        c_h_s = 1.5 + 14 * Math.Exp(-0.46 * Math.Sqrt(array2[1])) * dAr4elem;
        c_h_r = 1.5 + 14 * Math.Exp(-0.46 * Math.Sqrt(h_r)) * dAr4elem;
        d_h_s = 1.5 + 5 * Math.Exp(-0.9 * Math.Sqrt(array2[1])) * dAr4elem;
        d_h_r = 1.5 + 5 * Math.Exp(-0.9 * Math.Sqrt(h_r)) * dAr4elem;


        Console.WriteLine($"a_h_r {a_h_r.ToString()}" +
            $"\r\na_h_s= {a_h_s.ToString()}" +
            $"\r\nb_h_s= {b_h_s.ToString()}" +
            $"\r\nb_h_r= {b_h_r.ToString()}" +
            $"\r\nc_h_s= {c_h_s.ToString()}" +
            $"\r\nc_h_r= {c_h_r.ToString()}" +
            $"\r\nd_h_s= {d_h_s.ToString()}" +
            $"\r\nd_h_r= {d_h_r.ToString()}");

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0) //63
            {
                A_m = -3 * q;
                A_s = -1.5;
                A_r = -1.5;
                A_gr = A_m + A_r + A_s;// Затухание из-за влияния земли.
                double A_div = ((20 * Math.Log10(array2[3] / d_0)) + 11);// Затухание из-за геометрической дивергенции (из-за расхождения энергии при излучении в свободное пространство).
                double A_atm = Acoustics.a * array2[3] / 1000;// Затухание из-за звукопоглощения атмосферой [дБ].
                A = A_gr + A_div + A_atm;

                Console.WriteLine($"A_m= {A_m.ToString()} дБ" +
            $"\r\nA_s= {A_s.ToString()} дБ" +
            $"\r\nA_r= {A_r.ToString()} дБ" +
            $"\r\nA_gr= {A_gr.ToString()} дБ" +
            $"\r\nA_div= {A_div.ToString()} дБ" +
            $"\r\nA_atm= {A_atm.ToString()} дБ" +
            $"\r\nA= {A.ToString()} дБ");

            }
            ....
```

Comment: Не уж то заработало? О_о Но, с другой стороны это хорошо. Волшебные кнопочки с боку ответа, лучшая награда